How can use remote desktop from wan to lan?
The network structure in my room.
Optical Network Unit(192.168.1.1) -->pc1(192.168.1.3)
                                  -->home router(192.168.31.1)-->pc2(192.168.31.203)

I try to access remote desktop from pc1 (wan) to pc2(lan) with the rdesktop command:
rdesktop  -u user  -p password    192.168.31.203:3389  

It can't work,how can use remote desktop from wan to lan?

Only the home router thinks that the network with PC1 is "WAN" (as it's configured by default that way), but practically the two networks are more like "LAN1" and "LAN2".
If you want PC1 to reach 192.168.31.203:

Either your PC, or your ONU (acting as the default gateway for PC1), needs to have the correct route to 192.168.31.203 (or the entire 192.168.31.0/24 if you prefer).
As it is right now, all packets for this address are sent towards the ONU (PC1's default gateway), and the ONU sends them towards your ISP (its own default gateway), and the ISP just discards them.
So you need to define a custom route for 192.168.31.203 (or the entire 192.168.31.0/24) via home_router. Specifically, the 'via' address needs to be home_router's address that is facing the PC1 or the ONU.
As you didn't include all of the home_router's IP addresses in the diagram – specifically you didn't include its 'WAN' address, which would have to be the 'via' address from PC1's or ONU's perspective – I cannot provide a full example, but generally it would be like this:
Destination: 192.168.31.0/24
Gateway:     192.168.1.999


The home_router needs to allow those connections through its firewall rules. Because it thinks the connections come from 'WAN' (from its perspective), it'll likely have default firewall rules that block all inbound connections. Add an exception to allow connections from 192.168.1.3 (or from the entire 192.168.1.0/24).
(The router's NAT usually isn't an issue – NAT does not block anything in itself; its claimed additional "security" comes purely from the internal network being unrouted.)


Alternatively, if you cannot configure routes or the home_router's firewall, the second method is to literally treat it as "WAN-to-LAN":

On the home_router, set up a "port forwarding" or "virtual server" rule that redirects traffic from the router's own IP address to 192.168.31.203:3389.

From PC1, connect to the home_router's "WAN" IP address (again, not included in the diagram) instead of PC2's real address.


